# How to arrange 0,1,-1 digits at 6 positions (python)?

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I want to place three numbers [0,1,-1] at 6 positions. It should give 3^6 = 729 combinations. The code should return something like:

```
(0,0,0,0,0,0)
(0,0,0,0,0,1)
(0,0,0,0,0,-1)
(0,0,0,0,1,1)
(0,0,0,0,1,-1)
.
.
(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0)
(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1)
```

I tried using "itertools.permutations", but am confused about how to incorporate 0,1,-1 into it.

Comment: It seems like you want `itertools.product((0, 1, -1), repeat=6)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `itertools.product(*iterables, repeat=1)` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Use like:

```py
> product([-1, 0, 1], repeat=6)
[...]
 (1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1),
 (1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1),
 (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
 (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 0, 1, -1),
 (1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
 (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

Gets you `len(list(product([-1, 0, 1], repeat=6))) = 729`

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.product`

```
import iertools
assert(sum(1 for _ in itertools.product([-1, 0, 1], repeat=6)) == 3**6)
```

If you know `itertools.permutations` I think no more explanation is required.